# When sending ether to a contract, it fails silently

Tags: solidity

I'm getting a strange issue where if I send ether to a payable function, none of the events fire in that function, but I'm getting no error value in the Web3 callback.

I have this function:

```
function makeDatum(string dataStr)  payable returns (bool) {
    debug("datum");
    data[msg.sender].payment += msg.value;
}
```

The debug is an event I've made that sends whatever you give it to the listener:

```
event debug(string data);
```

Here is my Datum struct:

```
struct Datum {
    bool exists;
    bytes32 name;
    uint payment;
}
```

Now, if I exclude this line:

```
data[msg.sender] += msg.value;
```

The debug event fires properly. Also, if I send zero Wei, it works fine and debug fires. Only when I send a value of Wei greater than zero do I not get the debug event.

Here is how I'm sending Wei:

```
contract.methods.makeDatum("test").estimateGas({from: defaultAccount}, function(error, gas) {
    console.log("Gas estimate:" + gas);
    contract.methods.makeDatum("test").send({from: defaultAccount, gas:gas, value: 50000}, function(error, result) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log("error:" + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
});
```

The error parameter here is returning NULL, so solidity doesn't seem to be throwing any errors...it's just failing silently. I'm using Solidity compiler 0.4.13 with Truffle.

Comment: I'm inferring that you have a variable in your contract, like `mapping (address=>Datum) data`. Can you confirm? I'm not having any trouble getting your contract to emit events with a payment in Remix. What happens when you try in Remix?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the efforts in helping me debug. That was the confusing part for me: in Remix, it was running fine. The accepted answer pointed out that I wasn't providing the value along with the gas estimate and that's why it was failing; that turned out to be true, and it's running fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the unknown error is a wrong gas estimation when you send the transaction because the `estimateGas` function must include exactly the same parameters (arguments and value) as the transaction function, this has an impact on the gas estimation.

So you only have to pass `value: 50000`to the `estimateGas` function:

```
contract.methods.makeDatum("test").estimateGas({from: defaultAccount, value: 50000}, function(error, gas) {
    console.log("Gas estimate:" + gas);
    contract.methods.makeDatum("test").send({from: defaultAccount, gas:gas, value: 50000}, function(error, result) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log("error:" + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
});
```

I made a similar project using Truffle Framework ([here](https://github.com/gjeanmart/stackexchange/tree/master/24570-when-sending-either-to-a-contract-it-fails-silently)) and the output is clear:

**Without value**

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas
```

**With value**

```
{ tx: '0xfd7d3f0ca4cab4b8353dd41d19242e199308972b256ea6a742b1f07767df21bf',
  receipt:
   { transactionHash: '0xfd7d3f0ca4cab4b8353dd41d19242e199308972b256ea6a742b1f07767df21bf',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0xe4cdc1271791a1bc3f8390e56c62ab596d511fa3f6ccd812b87409511b58857e',
     blockNumber: 32,
     gasUsed: 44202,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 44202,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [ [Object] ] },
  logs:
   [ { logIndex: 0,
       transactionIndex: 0,
       transactionHash: '0xfd7d3f0ca4cab4b8353dd41d19242e199308972b256ea6a742b1f07767df21bf',
       blockHash: '0xe4cdc1271791a1bc3f8390e56c62ab596d511fa3f6ccd812b87409511b58857e',
       blockNumber: 32,
       address: '0xe973ea06c0caa83807de42ab870b6102785c9a72',
       type: 'mined',
       event: 'debug',
       args: [Object] } ] }
```

Comment: Thanks for this response; it solved my issue! I didn't realize you had to send the value with the gas estimate.